# Auto scroll banner images in a windows phone 8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I'm trying to implement autoscrolling and snapping to images in a windows phone 8 app
I currently have couple of images in a stackpanel inside a scrollviewer, and I'd like them to auto scroll horizontally every certain amount of time [5 seconds for example] while still being able to scroll and snap manually

this is what I have so far

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="featuredScroll" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <StackPanel x:Name="featuredStack" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Image  Source="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>
        <Image  Source="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>
        <Image  Source="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[images are placeholders]

so what I have now shows a scrollable list of those images [banners] which I can scroll horizontally, any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5439e6/image-slideshow-using-dispatchtimer-in-windows-store-apps/
How about this option? This is example for  Win store apps, but i don't see the reason why you couldn't rewrite it to WP